# OpenLayers is not defined

Tags: openlayers-2, openlayers

I have following HTML page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.3.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <style>
      .map {
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.3.0/build/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title>OpenLayers 3 example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>My Map</h2>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        controls: [
                        new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
                        new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar(),
                        new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher({'ascending':false}),
                        new OpenLayers.Control.Permalink(),
                        new OpenLayers.Control.ScaleLine(),
                        new OpenLayers.Control.Permalink('permalink'),
                        new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition(),
                        new OpenLayers.Control.OverviewMap(),
                        new OpenLayers.Control.KeyboardDefaults()
                    ],
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'sat'})
          }),
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
          }),
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
          center: ol.proj.transform([132.18333, 43.35], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
          zoom: 15
        })
      });
      map.addLayers([vector]);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I open it, it complains about `Uncaught ReferenceError: OpenLayers is not defined` at the line `new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),`.

How can I fix it?

Comment: You're mixing OpenLayers 2 and 3 code. OL2 uses the `OpenLayers.*` namespace, OL3 uses `ol.*`  namespace. How to fix it? Settle on one version and stick to it.

Answer (score 2):

That's because `OpenLayers.` is the v2.x namespace, also the controls have [changed a bit](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.3.0/apidoc/ol.control.html).